# Set of limits of a recursive sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, continuity

Take a continuous function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that for every non-negative integer $k$ there exists $u_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that the sequence defined by

$$ u_0\in \mathbb{R},\qquad \forall n\ge 0,\quad u_{n+1} = f(u_n) $$

converges to $k$. Can we find $u_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that the sequence defined by

$$ u_0\in \mathbb{R},\qquad \forall n\ge 0,\quad u_{n+1} = f(u_n) $$

diverges to $+\infty$? I don't know if the answer to this question is yes or no. One can easily see that if $f$ isn't continuous the answer is no. But what can we say is $f$ is continuous ?

Comment: Consider a function $f$ where $f(k)=k$ for all integer $k$ and $f(x)<x$ for non-integral $x$. What can you conclude?

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the exact question. The comment by Simply Beautiful can be more simplified: The function $f(x)=x$ fullfills the condition placed on $f$, but can't find an $u_0$ that when iterated goes to $+\infty$. I don't think that would have escaped the OP. I *think*  the question is meant: Does an $f$ exist where it is possible?
But I'm also confused by the OP's remark about a discontinous $f$, because the answer there is clearly "yes".

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit unclear what exactly the question is asking. We have as premise a condition on a continuous function $f$, and the question if $f$ fulfills the conclusion, another condition. The answer, as for most similar questions, is "It depends on which specific $f$ you are looking at!".

Simply Beautiful Art gave in the comments a hint to answer the question "Does a function $f$ that fulfills the premise necessarily also fulfill the conclusion?". That question can easily be answered with "No", and the simple

$$f(x)=x$$

is a counterexample. For any real $u_0$ we have $u_n=u_0\; \forall n \ge 0$, so the premise is fulfilled by setting $u_0=k$ for each non-negative integer $k$. The conclusion is obviously not fulfilled.

The question "Does a function exist that fulfills both the premise and the conclusion?" has the answer "Yes".

Define

$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
x   & \text{ if }x=k,\; k \in \mathbb Z \\
x+1 & \text{ if }x=k+\frac12,\; k \in \mathbb Z
\end{cases}
$$

then define $f$ continiuously between the given values, for example by linear interpolation.

For each $k\in \mathbb Z$, if we set $u_0=k$, we get $u_n=k\; \forall n \ge 0$, so this functions fulfills the premise.

If we set $u_0=\frac12$, then we get easily by induction that $u_n=n+\frac12, \;\forall n \ge 0$, so $\lim_{n\to \infty}u_n=+\infty$, so this proves the conclusion for this $f$.